# least squares regression Math.Net

Tags: c#, linear-regression

I am looking for some information on how to use Math.Net. I don't see any documentation on how to create a matrix using 36 Independent variables and 1 dependent variable. I would assume that if this is a normal matrix

```
var xdata = new double[] { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };
var ydata = new double[] { 15, 20, 25, 55, 95 };
```

A matrix that I am trying to create would be:

```
var xdata = new double[,] { { 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, 
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 }, 
        { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, 
        { 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, 
        { 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, 
        { 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 } };

        var ydata = new double[] { 5, 4, 7, 6, 6, 7 };
        Vector<double> p = MathNet.Numerics.LinearRegression.MultipleRegression.NormalEquations(xdata, ydata);
```

The 0,1 represent the 36 independent variables and the yData represents the dependent variables. Is this correct? I cannot get it to run correctly.

The line:

> Vector p = MathNet.Numerics.LinearRegression.MultipleRegression.NormalEquations(xdata, ydata);

does not like the data I am adding to it.

Ok I have done some looking around and found this:

```
double[] p = MultipleRegression.QR(
        new[] { new[] { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 }, new[] { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 }, new[] { 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 } },
        new[] { 6.0, 7.0, 5.0 },
        intercept: true);
```

This will run but it's return puzzles me: -16.4999999999999 1.95 
I would expect to see Constant, Effect, Coefficient, Standard Error, Std. Tolerance, tp-value, Coefficient

But what I just need is the Constant, and the Coefficient.
I see now the Double returned has 37 variables in it, the constant and the 36 elements great! but the issue is they do not match up with the variables I am getting if I ran it by hand. I guess I need to know how to find the Coefficient for the regression and to make sure I am using Linear Least Square Regression the documentation is not clear on it.

I have also tried to run this:

```
 var xdata = new double[] { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };
 var ydata = new double[] { 5.0 };
 double[] p = SimpleRegression.Fit(xdata, ydata);
```

With no luck it will not run correctly, it seems to want to have more ydata.

Comment: Try R.Net: https://rdotnet.codeplex.com/

Comment: Updated question to help remove onHold.

Comment: I edited and voted to reopen, but you really changed your question too much.  You should have just started a new question.

Comment: Sorry I am new to the site and still learning the way.